# Programmer /Debugger for freescale kinetis series

Tags: debugging, programmer, freescale, kinetis

I want to use frescale MK10 Device for my Project, the Cost of Programmer debugger is very high , so i Want to ask is there any low cost P/D ot any hack available with any system so that i can use that as P/D

Comment: CMSIS-DAP is not particularly fast with default packet sizes but widely available including as source code on mbed.  Atmel's boards and adapter use a version with larger packets that is substantially faster, and not limited to Atmel targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: FTDI based adapter and OpenOCD (eg. from [Olimex](https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/JTAG/ARM-USB-OCD/))

Option 2: K64-FRDM board has built-in JTAG, [that you can connect to an external board](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/04/21/using-the-freedom-board-as-jtag-programmer/) (it is fully supported by Kinetis Design Studio).

Option 3: get a [SEGGER J-Link with EDU license](https://www.segger.com/j-link-edu.html). It is much cheaper than the commercial version, but you can use it only for education/experimenting.

Personally I love using SEGGER tools to make a living, they work fast, they work reliably, every single time and it takes very little time to set up the drivers. J-links also support [RTT](https://www.segger.com/jlink-rtt.html) which basically is a "serial terminal" over JTAG, so you don't have to expose an UART on the PCB for debugging.